# blazor invokeMethodAsync.apply won't work

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to wrap the blazor call to `invokeMethodAsync`, usually I'm calling it like this and it works:

```
dobjref.invokeMethodAsync("Method1", p1, p2);
```

I wanted to wrap this call like this:

```
function invokeMethod() {        
    var ags = arguments;
    var dobjref = arguments[0];        
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    
    return dobjref.invokeMethodAsync.apply(dobjref, args);
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
invokeMethod(dobjref, "Method1", p1, p2)
```

but when this runs I'm getting

> JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32

at the server

Comment: Your question is unclear, but it seems like you are trying to use apply to pass an array of parameters.  The "spread syntax" might be a better solution.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I've tried the spread, it didn't work